# Is it OK to commit code written by a large model such as ChatGPT or Github Copilot?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, tools

Question inspired by a similar question in Academia.SE: [Is it OK to generate parts of a research paper using a large language model such as ChatGPT?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/191197/is-it-ok-to-generate-parts-of-a-research-paper-using-a-large-language-model-such)

I've always been very sceptical about AI code generation tools. My thinking is as follows:

- Such tools are known to sometimes output incorrect code. Sometimes the flaws are not obvious, bugs in subtle edge cases are introduced, these may even open security holes.
- Without full understanding of each and every line of code output by the AI I cannot guarantee that its code is free of such flaws.
- However, these tools are often praised because they allow people to skip looking for information, reading documentation, Googling, etc.
- This seems to me to be the most dangerous situation because if I don't do this work I cannot check the code.
- Conversely, if I do fully and deeply understand each and every line of code the AI outputs I could have just as easily written it myself.

For this reason it seems to me that the situation is binary:

- Either computers are good enough that I can just tell them in natural language what I want and they write correct code - in this case human developers are no longer needed and can all be fired;
- Or computers are not (yet) that good, in which case humans should write code on their own, without relying on such tools.

On top of that there is also a licensing problem - it is not clear if code output by such an AI is not plagiarized from somewhere, but the AI won't properly attribute code it found on GitHub.

However, apparently, the general sentiment is to the contrary. Programmers - including those I know to be very good programmers - praise ChatGPT and say that when they switched to telling OpenAI what to write in natural language and committing its code their efficiency rose *several hundred percent*.

What am I failing to see?

Comment: There is a lawsuit against Github copilot for breaching licensing and copyright restrictions, so I have avoided it. it uses "open source" code to train and has been caught red handed reproducing code from its training material which has restrictions that it does not inform the user about.

Comment: This is surely an interesting topic, but I think it will make some difference in which  context such code is used or "commiited". In your own homebrewn game? In a professional product? In an internal program for your company? For your companies website? In your next contribution to the Linux kernel? I recommend Spolsky's [Five Worlds](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/05/06/five-worlds/).

Comment: Recent Stack Overflow's blog post that I think worth a read: [Three types of AI-assisted programmers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/12/11/three-types-of-ai-assisted-programmers/ "Three types of AI-assisted programmers - Stack Overflow")

Answer (score 9):

At this time, I couldn't recommend that anyone use AI code generation tools in a professional context.

Although it's the domain of lawyers, there are still open questions about copyright, licensing and AI code generation. [Microsoft, GitHub, and OpenAI are being sued for violations of copyright law](https://www.theverge.com/2022/11/8/23446821/microsoft-openai-github-copilot-class-action-lawsuit-ai-copyright-violation-training-data), so maybe we'll get at least some answers soon. I doubt that this first case will result in sufficient answers to give confidence in the legal questions.

The concerns about the accuracy of the code are also valid. Generated code would have to be reviewed as closely, if not more closely, than code written by humans. The algorithms are only as good as the training sets and may have previously unknown security vulnerabilities or defects, or even have been trained on code that purposefully has vulnerabilities or defects. Human languages also tend to be ambiguous, so the typed requests to generate the code may not result in the right code for the task, which is a common problem when specifying requirements.

The current code generation tools, and many of the general-purpose AI tools out there, don't implement [explainable AI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explainable_artificial_intelligence). It's difficult, if not impossible, to understand why the output is what it is. Without a deep understanding of the training data and what was done to vet the training data for suitability in training the algorithm for a given application along with the ability to have the AI explain itself, it's difficult to build trust with these systems.

There's plenty of "cool" factors here, but I still see these tools in a toy phase. People who are blindly praising these tools may not be looking at the big picture of the legal and ethical landscape they are working in.

Comment: To play the devil's advocate. While I have no answers to the copyright problem, as far as I'm aware programmers who praise ChatGPT do not see its use as a compromise with quality. I talked to some programmers I know to be good who praised ChatGPT and I raised the point that ChatGPT cannot be trusted to output correct code; I claimed that it was irresponsible to commit code it writes without deep understanding of each and every line it outputs, and if I do have such full understanding I could just as well write the code myself. (con't)

Comment: I admit I have no answer to their response. They said: "*Of course, ChatGPT cannot be trusted to write correct code. However, junior devs also cannot be trusted to write correct code. Hell, no one in our team can be trusted to write correct code, which is why we emphasise code reviews and automated tests. And yet it is still far faster to tell junior devs to write code and then review their code than do everything myself. I never blindly commit ChatGPT's code, and yet I no longer manually write code myself. I tell ChatGPT what to do, then carefully review its code...*

Comment: "*...then carefully review its code, point out its shortcomings, make ChatGPT write tests to its own code, make ChatGPT fix bugs it introduced, and only when I decide the code is satisfactory I commit it. The work becomes similar to managing junior devs*". My understanding is that those who praise ChatGPT believe that AI has became a new paradigm in programming. As in days long gone programmers were translating business requirements to assembly code, until not long ago their job was rather to translate business requirements to Java, now programmers translate business reqs to ChatGPT.

Comment: Therefore, the programmers' core job does not change - it is, and has always been, translating business reqs to a language understandable by computer; however, the level of abstraction increases in time dramatically. I have heard claims that similar revolutions await many other professions, such as artists, clerks etc; rather than doing everything themselves, humans will tell the computer what to do, then look at what the computer outputs, make their instructions more precise, make the computer fix shortcomings, and such back-and-forth between the human and the computer will continue...

Comment: ...will continue until the human expert judges the computer's output satisfactory. ||| To sum up: Does this point of view not refute your points about how AI code generation tools cannot be trusted to generate accurate code?

Comment: @gaazkam it has been a year from when you asked the question. Do you have any update on this?